# Vue prop auto emitting nested data to parent component

Tags: html, vue.js

I have recently found something a little odd when using vue props.
I was led to believe that props have a oneway data flow (parent to child).

For some bizarre reason my props seem to be automatically emitting back so my v-model inputs within the child are changing the parent data it is based on (similar to the .sync() behavior). This only happens within a nested array of data within a object

***eg. the images array updates parent, everything else doesn't.***

- Why when editing the images array is the parent data being updated?
- I don't want the input for images to affect the parent, how can I stop this?

**Parent**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Parent Data</h1>
        <div v-if="testData">
            <p>{{testData.description}}</p>
            <p>{{testData.images[0].description}}</p>
            <p>{{testData.images[0].primary}}</p>
            <test :test="testData"></test>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import test from './test.vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            test
        },
        data() {
            return {
                testData: {
                    id: 71,
                    name: "test 105",
                    identifier: "test_105",
                    description: "test description here",
                    online: 1,
                    sort_order: 1,
                    images: [
                        {
                            id: 148,
                            name: "cities",
                            description: 'image description',
                            image_directory: "images/designs/148",
                            online: null,
                            primary: true,
                            sort_order: null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Child**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Child Input</h1>
        <input v-model="form.description" type="text" class="form-control" id="design-description" aria-describedby="name">
        <input v-if="form.images.length" v-model="form.images[0].description" type="text" class="form-control" id="image-description" aria-describedby="name">
        <input id="image-primary" v-if="form.images.length" v-model="form.images[0].primary" class="btn-toggle btn-toggle-round-flat" checked="true" type="checkbox">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        props: ['test'],
        data() {
            return {
                form: {
                    id: null,
                    name: null,
                    description: null,
                    online: true,
                    images: [],
                    catagory_ids: [],
                    fortysummers_reference: null
                },
                errors: [],
            }
        },
        mounted() {

            let activeDesign = this.test;

            this.form = {
                id: (activeDesign) ? activeDesign.id : null,
                name: (activeDesign) ? activeDesign.name : null,
                description: (activeDesign) ? activeDesign.description : null,
                online: (activeDesign) ? activeDesign.online : true,
                images: (activeDesign) ? activeDesign.images : [],
                catagory_ids: [],
                fortysummers_reference:
                    null
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`let activeDesign = this.test;` here actually 
value of this.test is not copied to activeDesign instead it is only referencing to parent's test data.
You need to copy value of this.test.
you can do something like this
`images: (activeDesign) ? [...activeDesign.images] : [],`
or use cloneDeep function of lodash
`let activeDesign = cloneDeep(this.test);`

Comment: Im not sure what [...array] is suppose to do? ...it doesn't achieve the desired  result. Thanks for the suggestions, not using lodash so looks like im going with 'jquery extend' as an alternative.

Comment: [...array] will spread the values of array removing reference untill element is object,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Answer (score 0):

Please see this page in the Vuejs documentation:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

> Note that objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference, so if the prop is an array or object, mutating the object or array itself inside the child will affect parent state.

To fix the problem, you can use clone, or you can also break out your attributes to send only simple types which are not passed by reference.

A better solution could be to use Vuex as a central store, since the core of your problem seems to be that you are using parent as your main data reference, which can get tricky due to these kind of issues. With Vuex, you will have explicit control over your data.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the details behind this...I will try Vuex out if this project gets much bigger. I will be using jQuery extend to clone and resolve this issue. I was wondering if you knew why a change to the nested array 'images' and not the actual parent object would cause this. eg `form.description` does not affect parent data, but `form.images.description` does.